# Python program unable to print one line having the same pattern like other lines

Tags: python

Python program unable to print one line having the same pattern like other lines

In my input file the last column is continent name. As there are three entries for ending with "Europe\n" pattern, but only the first and last are printed. I am using Python 3 in Ubuntu 14.04

```
#!/usr/bin/python

fh = open('countries.txt')
for line in fh:
        if line.endswith('Europe\n'):
           print line
exit()
```

Input:

```
India   1267    746     Asia
Mexico  762     78      North America
France  211     55      Europe
Japan   144     120     Asia
Germany 96      61      Europe
England 94      56      Europe
```

Output:

```
France  211 55  Europe

England 94  56  Europe
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to your code shows the problem:

```
for line in fh:
    print repr(line), line.endswith('Europe\n')
```

which gives:

```
'India   1267    746     Asia\n' False
'Mexico  762     78      North America\n' False
'France  211     55      Europe\n' True
'Japan   144     120     Asia\n' False
'Germany 96      61      Europe\n' True
'England 94      56      Europe' False
```

The last line **doesn't** include a newline `'\n'`, so it doesn't get printed. You should change the test from:

```
line.endswith('Europe\n')
```

to:

```
line.strip().endswith('Europe')
```

i.e. *"does the line end with `'Europe'` once the whitespace is removed?"* This gives:

```
'India   1267    746     Asia\n' False
'Mexico  762     78      North America\n' False
'France  211     55      Europe\n' True
'Japan   144     120     Asia\n' False
'Germany 96      61      Europe\n' True
'England 94      56      Europe' True
```

and in your code gives the desired results:

```
France  211     55      Europe

Germany 96      61      Europe

England 94      56      Europe
```

---

Note that you should really handle files with the context manager `with`:

```
with open('countries.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.strip().endswith('Europe'):
            print line
```

Comment: If Line with Germany is `True`, then why it is not printing? please check my output. I was not getting the line starting with Germany not England as shown in input

Comment: Well what happens if you include `print repr(line), line.endswith('Europe\n')`? I assumed you'd copied the wrong output, as when I run the code you provided on the data you provided I got the lines starting `'France'` and `'Germany'`, as I expected.

Comment: I got this out from the code you suggested. `'Germany\t96\t61\tEurope\t\n' False`. i understood the issue in the current problem. thanks for HELP.